# Windows 8 or Windows 8 pro

Tags: asp.net

I am planning to buy a new laptop which I will use for ASP.Net MVC4 projects.I will install Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and MS SQL Managemet studio. I will be working from home using remote desktop connection. Can I do all this using Windows 8 or should I buy Windows 8 Proffesional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a **Windows 8 Pro-license** since Windows 8 version doesn't support that as you can read at the [official comparison](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/buy?ocid=GA8_O_WOL_Hero_ShopHP_FPP_Null)